# How to make any object in you storyboard change with the iPhone screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, size, scale

By object I mean text field and images button and other objects in storyboard scaled to match and fit all screen sizes 5,4,6,X.

Comment: You can change size of views according to screen size using Autolayout

Comment: where i can find auto layout an if i set the width and the hight, top, buttom, constraint will that be an issue

Comment: Use AutoLayouts

Comment: Don't apply fix height and width just set leading trailing top and bottom

Answer (score 0):

[image]For this you need to assign auto layout constraints to object in such way that, width of object should be kept flexible and similarly for height also, if flexible height required

For width and height to match screen size set following constraints:

1. Object leading constraints to its superview
2. Object trailing constraint to its superview
3. Top space constraint to define y origin
   4  Bottom constraint to superview

for Width flexible but fixed height:
1. Object leading constraints to its superview 
2. Object trailing constraint to its superview
3. Top space constraint to define y origin
4  Hight constraint to specify value of height

You can also use size classes to give different width and height values according to device type.

Comment: where i can find auto layout an if i set the width and the hight, top, buttom, constraint will that be an issue

Comment: I have added image in answer

Comment: look man the problem is my UIimage is too big so if i do what you said and it's  cover the all area

Comment: sorry my internet was off @Mangesh Murhe

Comment: Can you show me picture of how exactly the screen should be?